# Extension of Brouwer's degree to continuous functions.

Tags: algebraic-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

I am studying the first chapter of this book:

[Topological Degree Theory and Applications](http://www.dim.uchile.cl/~ceimat/Material%20Docencia/MA48D/Primavera%202008/Material%20Adicional/Topological%20degree%20theory%20and%20applications%20-%20O%27Regan%20Cho%20Chen.pdf)

At page 13 of this document, Definition 1.2.5, it is essentially said that to define the degree of a continuous function $f$ we just approximate it by a function $g$ in $C^2$ and take its degree.

Now I can't see how to justify this from the previous proof:

we just showed that if $\Omega$ is open and bounded, $f\in C^2(\bar \Omega) $, $p \not \in f(\partial \Omega)$
and $|p'-p|<\operatorname{dist}(p,f(\partial \Omega)$ where $p',p $ are regular values of $f$ then

$$\operatorname{deg}(f,\Omega,p)=\operatorname{deg}(f,\Omega, p')$$

While what we actually need is that if $g_1,g_2 \in C^2(\bar \Omega)$ and $\max( {|g_1-f|,|g_2-f|)}< d(p, f(\partial \Omega))$ then

$$\operatorname{deg}(g_1,\Omega,p)=\operatorname{deg}(g_2,\Omega, p')$$

Essentially we need an homotopy invariance for smooth functions, or am I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "justify"? If you're simply asking of the definition is well-defined, the problem is this: let $g$ and $h$ be two different approximations of $f$ in $C^2$. You need to prove $g$ and $h$ have the same degree.

Comment: @Hurkyl yeah I was thinking if it is well defined...Does it follow immediately from the previous work?

Comment: @Moritzplatz: You should read this article, I found it clearer: http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/FULLTEXT/1959/8/58017

Comment: it is a lot clearer, thank you!